# jQuery UI Tabs - On DoubleClick Rename this Tab

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-tabs

I am using jQuery UI Tabs...

### Double click on tab name text to rename

Eg: On Double Click of "**Home 1**" Tab, **editable text field** should be visible with the label inside says(*this tab name*) "**Home 1**" and can be changed to other name i.e. "**Custom Tab**". As soon as I hit **Enter** button, this tab name should be changed to "**Custom Tab**"....

---

### [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ckpwdojt/3/)

---

> **HTML**

```
<div id="my-tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#Home-1">Home 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Home-2">Home 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Home-3">Home 3</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="Home-1">
        <p>Home Content 1</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Home-2">
        <p>Home Content 2</p>
    </div>
    <div id="Home-3">
        <p>Home Content 3</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

> **jQuery**

```
$(function() {
    var tabs = $( "#my-tabs" ).tabs();
    tabs.find( ".ui-tabs-nav" ).sortable({
        axis: "x",
        stop: function() {
            tabs.tabs( "refresh" );
        }
    });
});
```

> **This is what I am talking about**
>   [image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok Here is a workaround!!

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ckpwdojt/6/)**

**HTML**

```
 <li class="tab"><input class="txt" type="text"/><a href="#Home-1">Home 1</a></li>
 <li class="tab"><input class="txt" type="text"/><a href="#Home-2">Home 2</a></li>
 <li class="tab"><input class="txt" type="text"/><a href="#Home-3">Home 3</a></li>
```

**CSS**

```
input[type=text]
{
    display:none;
    width:120px;
}
a
{
    display:block;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.tab').on('dblclick',function(){
    $(this).find('input').toggle().val($(this).find('a').html()).focus();
    $(this).find('a').toggle();
});

$('.tab').on('blur','input',function(){
    $(this).toggle();
    $(this).siblings('a').toggle().html($(this).val());
});
```

**UPDATE**

**[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ckpwdojt/8/)**

Works for `enter keypress`, `blur` and `arrowkeys` wherein `arrowkeys` when pressed during edit mode, used to force textbox to loose focus!! below is the total fix:

```
$('.tab').on('keydown blur','input',function(e){
       if(e.type=="keydown")
       {
           if(e.which==13)
           {
               $(this).toggle();
               $(this).siblings('a').toggle().html($(this).val());
           }
           if(e.which==38 || e.which==40 || e.which==37 || e.which==39)
           {
               e.stopPropagation();
           }
       }
       else
       {
            if($(this).css('display')=="inline-block")
            {
                $(this).toggle();
                $(this).siblings('a').toggle().html($(this).val());
            }
       }
});
```

**UPDATE 2**

You need to check for `dblclick` event along with `blur` and `keydown` for the input as below:

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ckpwdojt/9/)**

```
$('.tab').on('keydown blur dblclick','input',function(e){
     if(e.type=="keydown")
     {
         if(e.which==13)
         {
            $(this).toggle();
            $(this).siblings('a').toggle().html($(this).val());
         }
         if(e.which==38 || e.which==40 || e.which==37 || e.which==39)
         {
            e.stopPropagation();
         }
     }
     else if(e.type=="focusout")
     {
         if($(this).css('display')=="inline-block")
         {
             $(this).toggle();
             $(this).siblings('a').toggle().html($(this).val());
         }
     }
     else
     {
         e.stopPropagation();
     }
});
```

Comment: Wow... @Guruprasad.... last example is working like a champ .... Thanks for your time... I have "Up Rated" and "Accepted" your answer... Keep up the good work...

Comment: Hey @Guruprasad... Sorry... There is some small issue still though... Even if I double click on Text Field, it is getting off...  Instead, if I double click on Textfield, it should select all the text inside textfield... Thanks for your work

Comment: @Reddy.. Check the latest demo!! :)

Comment: Yes... @Guruprasad Rao... This is what exactly I want it... Thanks a TON

Comment: Anytime... :) Happy Coding again.. :D

Comment: Sorry Again... why can't I use space inside the rename text field?

Comment: @Reddy.. Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/ckpwdojt/12/)**. Add one more option in `keydown` event 2nd `if` -> `|| e.keyCode == 32`

Comment: Add this code to cancel when hitting the escape key-
if( e.which==27)
           {
             $(this).toggle();
              $(this).siblings('a').toggle();
           }

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/ckpwdojt/5/

Here is the way. Enter key doesn't work in jsfiddle for some reason. So temporarily put it to Q.

```
    $("a").dblclick(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        $(this).next().show();
    });
    $('.hide').keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==113) { //for some reason enter doesn't work. keyCode ==13
            var input = $(this); 
            input.hide();
            $(this).prev().show().text(input.val());
        }    
    });
```